# What is the difference between title and display name

Tags: android, mediastore

I need the full name of a file (myFile.txt) and are looking at Title and Diaplay Name in [MediaColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns.html). Can you tell me the difference between the two and when to use which?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE
```

This is the title of the media file you want to play, for example `Westlife - My Love`. Use it as the title of the media, i.e music title, video title, etc.

```
MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME
```

This is the full name of the file without its path, included its extension.

For example `Westlife - My Love.mp3`

For more information, see [this reference](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=HyWyPCJ8ug0C&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=android%20MediaStore.MediaColumns%20title&source=bl&ots=EN4Fc9Vzlu&sig=8JoqFcQWKeKY5N_zlQNbLgs6z-o&hl=id&sa=X&ei=kbpxVYPyAoTxmAWqloGYCg&ved=0CFMQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=android%20MediaStore.MediaColumns%20title&f=false).

Comment: On my Galaxy S6 with API 23 DISPLAY_NAME doesn't include the extension. I haven't tested it on any other devices or API versions so I can't give more information, just be warned that it doesn't always include the extension.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch the complete path of the media file? Which column does it represent?

Comment: @MalwinderSingh You can, with [SimpleStorage](https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage).